# CoffeScript, Play! and Problems

Tags: javascript, jquery, playframework, coffeescript

I've been experimenting with the Play! framework for a few weeks now and have got half way through the Zen tasks sample application and seems to be a large gap in information from [chapter 5 to 6](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.0/JavaGuide6).

I have created the main.coffee file as described and the application compiles fine, however I am getting the following error "*Uncaught TypeError: Property 'children' of object #`<HTMLUListElement>` is not a function*".

This would imply that I'm trying to call jQuery on a HTML element, however I have literally copied and pasted from the sample so cannot understand what I could have done, it must work for the guys who wrote the tutorial right?!

Anyway, I'm using Play 2.2.0 and the coffeescript has been written as below...

```
class Drawer extends Backbone.View

$ -> 
   drawer = new Drawer el: $("#travelgroups")

class Drawer extends Backbone.View
initialize: ->
    @el.children("li").each (i,group) ->
        new Group
            el: $(group)
        $("li",group).each (i,travelgroup) ->
            new TravelGroup
                el: $(travelgroup)
```

The section of the generated main.js file that is showing the error is below

```
    Drawer.prototype.initialize = function() {
  return this.el.children("li").each(function(i, group) {
    new Group({
      el: $(group)
    });
    return $("li", group).each(function(i, travelgroup) {
      return new TravelGroup({
        el: $(travelgroup)
      });
    });
  });
};
```

As a secondary question, should the coffee file itself contain 'inner' class declarations or should separate .java class files be created? Like I said there's a large gap in detailed explanations between tutorial chapters so am a little confused as coffescript is completely new to me and have never seen class declarations outide of actual .java class files before?

EDIT...

The complete coffee script file is below. The indentations were already as they are.

```
$(".options dt, .users dt").live "click", (e) ->
    e.preventDefault()
    if $(e.target).parent().hasClass("opened")
        $(e.target).parent().removeClass("opened")
    else
        $(e.target).parent().addClass("opened")
        $(document).one "click", ->
            $(e.target).parent().removeClass("opened")
    false

$.fn.editInPlace = (method, options...) ->
    this.each ->
        methods = 
            # public methods
            init: (options) ->
                valid = (e) =>
                    newValue = @input.val()
                    options.onChange.call(options.context, newValue)
                cancel = (e) =>
                    @el.show()
                    @input.hide()
                @el = $(this).dblclick(methods.edit)
                @input = $("<input type='text' />")
                    .insertBefore(@el)
                    .keyup (e) ->
                        switch(e.keyCode)
                            # Enter key
                            when 13 then $(this).blur()
                            # Escape key
                            when 27 then cancel(e)
                    .blur(valid)
                    .hide()
            edit: ->
                @input
                    .val(@el.text())
                    .show()
                    .focus()
                    .select()
                @el.hide()
            close: (newName) ->
                @el.text(newName).show()
                @input.hide()
        # jQuery approach: http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring
        if ( methods[method] )
            return methods[ method ].apply(this, options)
        else if (typeof method == 'object')
            return methods.init.call(this, method)
        else
            $.error("Method " + method + " does not exist.")


class Drawer extends Backbone.View

$ -> 
     drawer = new Drawer el: $("#travelgroups")

class Drawer extends Backbone.View
    initialize: ->
        @el.children("li").each (i,group) ->
            new Group
                el: $(group)
            $("li",group).each (i,travelgroup) ->
                new TravelGroup
                    el: $(travelgroup)

class Group extends Backbone.View
    events:
        "click    .toggle"          : "toggle"
        "click    .newTravelGroup"  : "newTravelgroup"
    toggle: (e) ->
        e.preventDefault()
        @el.toggleClass("closed")
        false
    newProject: (e) ->
        @el.removeClass("closed")
        r = jsRoutes.controllers.TravelGroups.add()
        $.ajax
            url: r.url
            type: r.type
            context: this
            data:
                group: @el.attr("data-group")
            success: (tpl) ->
                _list = $("ul",@el)
                _view = new TravelGroup
                    el: $(tpl).appendTo(_list)
                _view.el.find(".name").editInPlace("edit")
            error: (err) ->
                $.error("Error: " + err)

class TravelGroup extends Backbone.View
```

AND HTML AS BELOW... group.scala.html

```
@(group: String, travelgroups: List[TravelGroup])

<li data-group="@group">
    <span class="toggle"></span>
    <h4 class="groupName">@group</h4>
    <span class="loader">Loading</span>
    <dl class="options">
        <dt>Options</dt>
        <dd>
            <button class="newTravelGroup">New travel group</button>
            <button class="deleteGroup">Remove group</button>
        </dd>
    </dl>
    <ul>
        @travelgroups.map { travelgroup =>
            @views.html.travelgroups.item(travelgroup)
        }
    </ul>
</li>
```

item.scala.html...

```
@(travelgroup: TravelGroup)

<li data-project="@travelgroup.id">
    <a class="name" href="#">@travelgroup.name</a>
    <button class="delete" href="#">Delete</button>
    <span class="loader">Loading</span>
</li>
```

Comment: Your indentation is a mess, please fix it. Indentation is *extremely* significant in a CoffeeScript program, and right now your program contains several errors. How can we tell the errors you've introduced in pasting your code, vs the errors that actually exist?

Comment: I've tried to stick to the tutorial letter for letter, and the instructions would imply (without actually saying so), that 2 declarations should be made, or I'm just reading it incorrectly? Meager: please see edited post for further code example with correct indentation. Thanks for your help

Comment: You have class Drawer declared twice in the file. Also you may check out the code here https://github.com/playframework/playframework/tree/master/samples/java/zentasks